# Python Web Importer - load submodules

Tags: python, import

I have a little edited the WebImporter class from this [site](http://blog.dowski.com/2008/07/31/customizing-the-python-import-system/).

```
import imp
import sys
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def register_domain(name, url):
    WebImporter.registered_domains[name] = url

class WebImporter:
    registered_domains = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        print('FIND', fullname, path)
        if fullname in self.registered_domains:
            return self
        if fullname.rsplit('.')[0] not in self.registered_domains:
            return None
        try:
            r = self._do_request(fullname, method="HEAD")
        except ValueError:
            return None
        else:
            r.close()
            if r.status == 200:
                return self
        return None

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        if fullname in sys.modules:
            return sys.modules[fullname]
        mod = imp.new_module(fullname)
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__name__ = fullname
        mod.__package__ = ['/'.join(fullname.split('.'))]
        mod.__path__ = '/'.join(fullname.split('.'))
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod
        if fullname not in self.registered_domains:
            url = self._get_host_and_path(fullname).geturl()
            mod.__file__ = url
            r = self._do_request(fullname)
            code = r.read()
            assert r.status == 200
            exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        else:
            mod.__file__ = "[fake module %r]" % fullname
            mod.__path__ = []
        return mod

    def _do_request(self, fullname, method="GET"):
        url = self._get_host_and_path(fullname)
        c = http.client.HTTPConnection(url.netloc)
        c.request(method, url.path)
        return c.getresponse()

    def _get_host_and_path(self, fullname):
        tld, rest = fullname.rsplit('.', 1)
        path = "/%s.py" % rest.replace('.', '/')
        url = self.registered_domains[fullname.split('.')[0]] + path
        url = urlparse(url)
        return url

sys.meta_path.append(WebImporter())
```

I have two modules on my web server on a local network:

foo.py (file at: http://192.168.122.2:80/foo.py):

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print('FOO')
```

bar.py (file at: http://192.168.122.2:80/bar.py):

```
from foo import foo

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        foo.__init__(self)
        print('BAR')
```

when I run:

```
import webimport
webimport.register_domain('dev', 'http://192.168.122.2:80')

from dev.foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

it imports and runs the code

but when I want to import and run the bar:

```
import webimport
webimport.register_domain('dev', 'http://192.168.122.2:80')

from dev.bar import bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar()
```

the output is:

```
FIND foo None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dev.bar import bar
  File "/home/user/tests/webimport/webimport.py", line 44, in load_module
    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'foo'
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add path of foo module to PYTHONPATH. If you're using bash (on a Mac or GNU/Linux distro), add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

**EDITED**

try to change in bar.py

```
from foo import foo
```

to

```
from dev.foo import foo
```

Comment: Both of those files are on a webserver, on on my local machine